# Chamada a webservice com um XML

Tags: java, .net, web-service, xml, restful

Tenho que desenvolver um webservice (rest) em java que vai ser chamado por um add-in do excel desenvolvido em .NET. 
    Esse plugin têm que enviar um xml, o que fiz foi transformar numa string só que o XML é enorme. Um string não tem espaço suficiente para alocar todo o ficheiro. Alguma dica como enviar o ficheiro xml para o web service ?

Obrigado

Comment: Pra testar eu utilizo o [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html)

Comment: Mas ja testei e tenho o problema de ele nao aeitar uma string tão longa, o XML é enorme. Precisava era de uma dica de como resolver